# Socrates is mortal

Tags: alloy

```
All men are mortals.
Socrates is a man.
Therefore, Socrates is a mortal.
```

Below an Alloy model to express that inference rule. Is that a good way to express the inference rule? Can you provide a better way to express it?

```
abstract sig man {}

// Socrates is a man
one sig Socrates extends man{}
one sig Plato extends man{}
one sig Aristotle extends man{}

one sig Earthly {
    mortals: set man
}

// All men are mortal
fact All_men_are_mortal {
    all m: man | m in Earthly.mortals
}

// Therefore, Socrates is mortal
assert Socrates_is_mortal {
    Socrates in Earthly.mortals   
}
check Socrates_is_mortal
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it closer to the natural language formulation, you might write something like this:

```
assert Syllogism {
  all Socrates: univ, Man, Mortal: set univ |
      -- every man is mortal
      Man in Mortal
      -- Socrates is a man
      and (Socrates in Man)
      -- implies Socrates is mortal
      implies Socrates in Mortal
  }

check Syllogism
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome! Thank you @Daniel Jackson

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I did this a couple of weeks ago.

In your definition you already put the that Socrates is a man in the sigs. this basically makes the syllogism superfluous since you already stated Socrates is a men.

I think that you therefore need a model where Socrates is not by definition in men.

In short, my version for the correct use of the syllogism

```
sig Men{}
one sig Socrates {}

check Correct {

    all mortal, men : some Men + Socrates {

        men in mortal
        and  
        Socrates in men 
        => Socrates in mortal

    }
} for 5 Men
```

If you check this then there are no counterexamples, so we seem to be ok.

However, it is easy to screw up with Syllogism's:

- All men are mortal.
- Socrates is a mortal.
- Therefore Socrates is a man.

This can be done in Alloy as follows

```
check Wrong {

    all mortal, men : some Men + Socrates {

        men in mortal
        and  
        Socrates in mortal 
        => Socrates in men

    }
} for 5 Men
```

When we check this we get a version where Socrates is in moral but not in men.

You can find an html version [here](http://aqute.biz/syllogism.html) and the source for this [here](https://github.com/pkriens/pkriens.github.io/blob/master/syllogism.md). These use the new proposed Alloy 5 markdown format.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
sig Mortal {}
sig Man extends Mortal {}
one sig Socrates extends Man {}

check {Socrates in Mortal}
```

Comment: Thank you @wmeyer